# How to get set up a GeoJson map with OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, geojson, price

My website currently uses mapbox as the base map: www.livehazards.com

The amount of views for the mapbox are for some reason, nearly 10x as high as Google Adsense views, meaning if I were to ever get 10,000+ visitors a day it would be financially unsustainable ($50 a day).

Here are some questions:

I've heard OSM is free to use, there are no charges for x amount of views - is this correct?

I know the base map would be different but would I be able to import GeoJson Earthquake data and style the data (Circle border, circle animation) similarly as I have with mapbox?

How can I get started with embedding an interactive OSM map on my website and how I would go about importing GeoJson Earthquake data within an OSM map?

Code:

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(mymap);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
  <style>
    body,html,#mapid { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I've heard OSM is free to use,there are no charges for x amount of views is this correct" -> No. OSM *data* is free. But running servers costs money, someone has to pay for it. Therefore there are certain limits for most OSM-based services. But since the data (and most software) is free you can set up your own services if you run into these limits.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply, does anyone know what the limits are?

Comment: This depends on the exact service. Just read the usage policy / terms of use of the service you are using.

Comment: Ok, thanks do you know the answer to my second question. Can you import Geojson files onto OSM and can you style the way I have on my map

Comment: I guess this is possible with Leaflet or OpenLayers but I don't have much experience with these libraries. You might be better off at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are some OSM usage guidelines [here](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). You could get in touch with them if you are unsure. Also, you can set up your own tile server - at higher loads this might be necessary.

Comment: Can anyone else give mean example on how to set a GeojSon map using OSM, thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, to clarify a bit of terminology, OpenStreetMap (OSM) is the database. There are many different providers of raster or vector tile services derived from OSM, and openstreetmap.org is itself one - with "reasonable use" guidelines. You don't "import" data "within" an OSM map, but you can "overlay" data "over" tiles provided by openstreetmap.org or anywhere else.

So, how do you overlay GeoJSON data over a raster tileset? Easy, use Leaflet and follow the [quick start tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) and the [GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/). The crucial parts:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);


var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};


L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the reply. I tried to add that to my page but nothing is displaying www.livehazards.com/sidebar-test. Any idea what is wrong. Ill put the code in an answer